# Single phase energy meter measurement

Tags: power, power-factor-correction

In a single phase meter measurement, the power is being measured by using the instantaneous power which is p(t) = v(t) * i(t). But as we need to sample the voltage and current to get the power, hence it need to be calculated by using this formula:

[image]

[image]

So is this formula can really measured the real active power without considering the phase angle between V and I? As we all know that active power, P = VIcosθ.

So what is the difference between apparent power measurement, S=VI and active power measurement if the P = VIcosθ is not being implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instantaneous Volts multiplied by instantaneous Amps is true power and no compromise and when micros implement this they are doing it exactly the correct way.

VI x power factor may not be true power because hardly ever is the voltage waveform or the current waveform truly sinusoidal and only when V and I are truly sinusoidal can RMS Voltage multiplied by RMS current multiplied by power factor = v(t). i(t).

Here are several examples of voltage and current waveforms shifted in phase to each other: -

[image]

The first picture is when v and i are in phase and power is maximum. Note also the example when v and i differ by 90 degrees (bottom left) - power is zero (as you would expect) but, if there is any harmonic distortion, VICos(phi) will be inaccurate.