# Calculating Energy Consumption Using a Current Sensor and Voltage Sensor

Tags: ac, current-measurement, mains, energy, monitor

I'm creating a PCBA that uses a hall-effect sensor to measure current and a transformer rectifier design to measure the mains voltage.  The voltage is 110-240 V, ~60 Hz. I wrote a digital filter and average the current every 1 based on 120 samples per second, taking the maximum and minimum values to get the Vpp of the waveform.

I then use I(A) * V(V) = P(W)
I do that calculation every second and store it in an array.
I then created a timer function that counts seconds, minutes and hours.
But I seem to be getting errors in my Wh calculation.
I want to sum up total energy used for a period of time, like how long the washer or dryer runs for.

So my equation is P(Wh) = Watts(avg/minute) * (minutes-sense-current-started/60)
The idea seems simple, but my total energy keeps jumping around.

Timer Function:

```
void mesure_time_pased(int status){
    if(status == 1){
        if (millis() >= (previousTime))
        {
            previousTime = previousTime + 1000;  
            seconds = seconds +1;
            if (seconds == 60)
            {
                seconds = 0;
                minutes = minutes +1;
            }
            if (minutes == 60)
            {
                minutes = 0;
                hours_1 = hours_1 +1;
            }
            if (hours_1 == 13)
            {
                hours_1 = 1;
            }
        // Serial.print (hours_1, DEC);
        // Serial.print (":");
        // Serial.print (minutes,DEC);
        // Serial.print (":");
        // Serial.println(seconds,DEC);
        } // end 1 second
    }else if (status == 0) {
       seconds = 0;
       minutes = 0;
       hours_1 = 0;
    }
}
```

I then use this logic to calculate the energy - is there a better way to do this?

```
if( charge_status == 200 && relay_status == 1){   
        if(millis() > data_collection_time + DATA_COLLECT_INTERVAL){
        data_collection_time = millis();
        uint32_t timestamp = Time.now();
        currentValue = asc711_digital_filer(CURRENT_SENSSOR_INPUT);
            if(currentValue <= 0)
            {
                currentValue = 0.00;
            }
        watt_energy = mains_voltage * currentValue ;
        if(watt_energy >= 0){
            total_watt_hours = (watt_energy * hours_1) + (watt_energy + (minutes/60)) + (watt_energy + (seconds/3600)) ;
        }
        op_amp_adc_in = analogRead(CURRENT_SENSSOR_INPUT);
        pcb_temp = NTCS0805E3103JMT_thermistorReading(THERMISTOR_ONE);
        relay_temp = PT103J2_thermistorReading(THERMISTOR_TWO);
        LM95071_temp =  SPI_Sensor.getTemperature();
        sensor_data = String::format( "{ \"sessionid\":\"%s\",  \"timestamp\":%u, \"current\":%0.2f, \"voltage\":%i, \"watts\":%0.2f, \"totalwattshours\":%0.2f, \"temppcb\":%0.2f, \"temprelay\":%0.2f, \"lm95071temp\":%.02f }", strsessionid, timestamp, currentValue, mains_voltage, watt_energy, total_watt_hours, pcb_temp, relay_temp, LM95071_temp);
        charge_session_data_blob.concat(sensor_data);
        // Serial.println(sensor_data);
        }
        if(millis() > time_send_data + INTERVAL_SEND_DATA_TO_CLOUD)
        {
            time_send_data = millis();
            Particle.publish("charge_session_data_blob", sensor_data , PRIVATE, WITH_ACK);
            charge_session_data_blob = "";
        }
}
```

I would love to create something more efficient at tracking time and totaling the energy used. I'm open to new ideas as I've tried a few and this is the best I've come to and I'm still not happy with it.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: What are you comparing against, in order to determine that you aren't getting good values? (I believe you, I just want to know how you know what you know.) Also, how do you take into account the power factor? Or do you intend to do so, at all? (And obviously, it's worth worrying about efficiency only after you get the right results.)

Comment: As a matter of interest, what is a "PCBA" (first paragraph)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I'm creating a PCBA that uses a hall-effect sensor to measure current
>   and a transformer rectifier design to measure the mains voltage.*

And

> *But I seem to be getting errors in my Wh calculation*

You don't measure power or watt hours that way. You are bound to get errors. Power is measured by multiplying the raw voltage AC waveform with the raw current AC waveform: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/202667/whats-the-most-economical-way-to-digitally-measure-240v-mains-voltage-current) and [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/126400/single-phase-energy-meter-measurement).

In order to avoid the effect of distorted current waveforms affecting the results you need to sample simultaneously both voltage and current waveforms AND at a high enough rate (typically 1 kSps for moderate accuracy).